# How do I cover up old text when double buffering? - Win32 C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to rapidly update text using double buffering.  I draw the text on top of a bitmap and blit it to the screen. But the text is never covered up as more is drawn, so before it's just an unreadable jumble of overwritten letters.  Here is my double buffering routine:

```
void PaintControlWindow()
{
    HDC hdc,hdcMemory;
    RECT rect;
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    HBRUSH backgroundBrush;

    hdc = GetDC(windowHwnd); //windowHwnd is a valid global
    GetClientRect(windowHwnd,&rect);
    hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 800, 600);
    backgroundBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,189,156));
    SelectObject(hdcMemory, bitmap);
    FillRect(hdcMemory,&rect,backgroundBrush);

    HDC hdcMemory2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcMemory);
    SelectObject(hdcMemory2,previouslyLoadedBitmap);

    SelectObject(hdcMemory2,previouslyCreatedFont);
    DrawTextEx(hdcMemory2,sometext,strlen(sometext),&bitmapBounds,DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE, NULL);

    BitBlt(hdcMemory, bitmapBounds.left, bitmapBounds.top, bitmapBounds.right, bitmapBounds.bottom, hdcMemory2, 0,0, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteDC(hdcMemory2);

    BitBlt(hdc, rect.left, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hdcMemory, rect.left, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
    DeleteObject(bitmap);
    DeleteObject(backgroundBrush);
    ReleaseDC(windowHwnd,hdc);
}
```

If I do a FillRect on the bitmapBounds rectangle in which I'm drawing the text all is well except that the bitmap that is supposed to be underneath the text gets covered up.

Thanks.

Comment: is there a real need for hdcMemory2?  Unless I am mistaken can't you do all your off-screen rendering in hdcMemory and just blit that to the window's DC?  Also, is it not better to handle the WM_PAINT message and blit hdcMemory at that point, keeping this function to just update the memory dc when necessary (and then invalidating the window to cause a WM_PAINT)?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, I think so.  I'm also drawing a bunch of other bitmaps with text onto the screen, but I just gave one here to simplify the code. WM_PAINT won't work for me; The values I'm drawing are updated 10-20 times a second by a timer and the display has to stay in sync with the values.  I don't think events can guarantee that precision.  For the record, I don't call CreateCompatibleBitmap each draw, I just do it once at window creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Moo-Juice's comments is relevant is several ways that you should think about. But the root of your problem is fairly easy to explain.

You have the right idea in general that is you should:

1. Have the preloaded background in a DC (such as hdcMemory2) so that you don't have to keep reloading it.
2. Copy that bitmap into another in memory DC
3. Draw Text on this DC
4. Copy the new DC to the screen

However you current code doesn't do that - when you draw text to hdcMemory2 (which has the previously loaded BM in it) this CHANGES the contents of this bitmap - which is not what you want. To get this to work as you intend you need to leave your hdcMemory2 unchanged, copy its contents into hdcMemory, and then draw the text onto hdcMemory (thus preserving the original image and only messing with the temporary copy). And then obviously copy it onto the screen.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize writing on hdcMemory2 was actually writing on the bitmap loaded there.